# Get Time Since Last Method call

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to be able to get the time since the method was called. Basically if I called a method 1 time and waited 50 second and called it again I need to be able to get the 50 seconds. I am not calling the method it is being called automatically when two sprite collides. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of static or global or member variable where you can store timestamp of last call. From current timestamp and last call timestamp, you can take diff and get the time since last method call.

As method belongs to a class, you can store in the object and update each time you call it.

```
@interface Myclass:NSObject
{
  int64_t timestamp; //Initialize it with the creation of the object or 0.
}
-(void) myMethod
@end

@implementation Myclass
-(void) myMethod
{
   //take diff from last timestamp

       int64_t ts = get_current_time_stamp();//Implement this yourself
       //get diff
       timestamp = ts;


}
@end
```